# find association by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a User model that has_many friends. I want to be able to find all the friends of a user by name.

I want to be able to find all users with the string "john" in their username.

Users

```
id   |           email           |         created_at         |         updated_at         |                       password_digest                        |     remember_token     | admin |   username    | password_reset_token | password_reset_sent_at | provider | uid | generated_password
-------+---------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+-------+---------------+----------------------+------------------------+----------+-----+--------------------
 27288 | ******@hotmail.com | 2014-02-19 17:25:22.545866 | 2014-02-19 17:25:22.545866 | $2a$10$hjdAPWYTorCN7NW6QawmtOMqTk.DP8m2e.I9XjfujRG8em8eq6z9G | dxowM5tTTalNLWSO_5j8sw | f     | huntingtonl93 |                      |                        |          |     | f
    23 | *******@gmail.com             | 2013-07-05 17:18:59.64622  | 2013-07-05 17:18:59.64622  | $2a$10$4D0cML22vnVYuT0tJTJwMO/T4xuiGYUU70BnK1ug3K.TE1.pWG64e | FS2aVM57bX0ZiMBNuWnxLA | f     | one           |                      |                        |          |     | f
    31 | ********@gmail.com       | 2013-09-06 21:47:52.869246 | 2013-09-06 21:47:52.869246 | $2a$10$XW6jPGZTiYo6KZm4WWOBye0b.mpNuKGt89gMLVRCjF7kjuhzHXzJG | TUsweMN36i_eouveEFU9cQ | f     | drebenok      |                      |                        |          |     | f
  6388 | *******@startupv8.com        | 2013-11-25 00:20:44.124276 | 2013-11-25 00:20:44.124276 | $2a$10$O5V/8C2vs.CpkYDDwByjiOOVkf0FlWb8lsMVX/r8cPnHbL8G0gRda | 2duwh0WURFI10I1PcBnD9Q | f     | ihab
```

Friends

```
id | user_id | user_id_friend |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+---------+----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 10 |      15 |             23 | 2013-08-13 01:55:41.406368 | 2013-08-13 01:55:41.406368
 12 |      15 |             28 | 2013-08-13 01:55:57.025223 | 2013-08-13 01:55:57.025223
 14 |      16 |             23 | 2013-08-13 01:57:35.910647 | 2013-08-13 01:57:35.910647
 16 |      17 |             23 | 2013-08-13 01:58:01.051038 | 2013-08-13 01:58:01.051038
 18 |      17 |             24 | 2013-08-13 01:58:08.866769 | 2013-08-13 01:58:08.866769
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding conditions to your association like so:

```
user.friends.where("username like ?", '%john%')
```

This involves just a little bit of SQL knowledge. We want the username to be "like" the string we give it. The string itself ('%john%') will match any username that contains "john" somewhere inside. The "%" is a wildcard character that will match any characters that might come before or after "john".

If you only wanted to find users whose usernames *start* with john, you would do it like so:

```
user.friends.where("username like ?", "john%")
```

If you only wanted to find users whose usernames *end* with john, you do this instead:

```
user.friends.where("username like ?", "%john")
```

This approach can be applied to any conditions you would use when searching in ActiveRecord. For instance, you could find all of a users's friends who don't have e-mail addresses:

```
user.friends.where(email: nil)
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can quite easily do it with gem "Ransack". It allows you to perform searches like that with ease.

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack